# Factors affecting hardness of water - EDTA titration

Tags: water, titration

I am thinking of doing a project involving EDTA complexometric titration to determine the hardness of the water. I am not sure if the pH will affect the hardness of the water. If it did, I would control it by changing the buffer solution's pH. If buffer pH does not affect the hardness of the water, are there any other factors that I could potentially explore.

Thanks

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88183/determination-of-hardness-of-water-using-edta

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44778/is-water-hardness-dependent-more-on-calcium-or-magnesium https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57720/how-do-i-determine-the-amount-of-calcium-in-a-substance-using-edta-titration